# Front-end error displaying architecture in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-5

So I am doing the error handling in my Laravel 5 application, specially the front-end part, where the user will see that some error happened.

I have the idea of having a simple error displaying page, that will receive errors and display in the browser for the user. (perhaps one variable with the error code and another with the description)

So, maybe an example would be create a function

```
public function displayErrors($errors){
    return view('auth.activationpending')->with('errors', $errors);
}
```

The view would then display it to the user.

Since this is a something very common to any website, I wonder if there something like that embedded in the laravel libraries already? Or maybe a better way to do it.. I'm concerned maybe I won't be able to redirect every error by default to this function/page.

Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you add the following to your Controller method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    //Do stuff
}
```

If the fields from the submitted form don't comply with the validation rules, you will be redirected back and have available `$errors->all()` to iterate, such as:

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $message)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This is only one example of many on how to retrieve validation errors, but should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are two type of error which need different behaviors in web application:

- *Error from user input*: when the input from user does not pass our validation rules, these errors need displaying to users. I usually redirect the user back to the page they entered data with an alert message about what data was wrong. I created and package for this error type and you can look at one of my post about it [here](https://www.hieule.info/products/laravel-v4-v5-global-site-message-system/).
- *Error with the application code*: in production environment, you **should not** display these error out, which can show some sensitive information about your code. The most common way is return the user a 500 error page and log the error details into log file (or similar things), which is implement as default in Laravel.